# Access context inside Dio Interceptor to trigger BloC event

Tags: flutter, dio

I want to trigger a bloc event inside a dio interceptor (to be precise an `onError` Interceptor) but for that I need `context` so I can do something like ->

```
BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context).add(MyEvent);
```

I try to relog a user if I catch a `401 Unauthorised` with values stored in secure storage. My Login Logic is stored inside a BloC that gets an event with login params. If it fails at first because the JWT Token expired or something else went wrong  I would like to launch an event here to handle any further problems (Refresh Logic, Re-Login Logic, ...) like so:

```
dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
  onError: (e, handler) {
    String? errorCode = e.response?.statusCode.toString();
    print("Dio Error Code caught: " + errorCode!);

    BlocProvider.of<LoginManagerBloc>(context).add(LoginWithEmail(mail:mail , pw: digest.toString()));
  },
));
```

**How do I get my `context` here? Is it even possible? Does it make sense or is it bad practise?**

Still getting to grips with Flutter as a whole and this part is still confusing me and I could not find a proper solution for it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you find out?